# javascript: use addEventListener event object E to finds coordinates of the click and then add a rectangular shape at the same location on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, addeventlistener, game-development

need help!!! i am following this new javascript 2D gaming video and i am currently stuck on 2:32:29 where we are making an explosion effect on canvas where the mouse clicked. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFO_txvwK_c&t=9365s.

problem: whenever i click on the canvas, no sqaure shapes shows up, in the tutorial it mentioned you will have to offset the e.x and e.y to make it relative the canvas. but i realized whenever i click the top left corner of the screen. sometimes an elongated rectangular shape does appear but when i offset my e.x and e.y. i can not get the correct offset to make it work. could anyone help explain why i am getting this weird offset effect on my event.x and event.y values and how to fix it? thanks a lot!!! you can see the thrid picture attached for my code adding the offset suggested by video and it still does not work.

```
const canvas=document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas,height = 700;
const explosion =[];

class Explosion {
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.spriteWidth = 200;
        this.spriteHeight = 179;
        this.width = this.spriteWidth/2;
        this.height = this.spriteHeight/2;
        this.image = new this.image();
        this.image.src = "boom.png";
        this.frame=0;
    }

    update(){
        this.frame++;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.spriteWidth*this.frame,0,this.spriteWidth,this.spriteHeight,this.x,this.y,this.width, this.height);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    ctx.fillStyle= 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(e.x,e.y,50,50);

})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKK3n.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC47k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqp87.png)

Comment: You may wanna start with fixing the  typo in line 4 (comma instead of dot). Should fix the "elongated rectangles" issue.

Comment: thanks for the help!!! sorry i am really new and found it annoying that JavaScript does not tell me whenever there is a typo....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wouldn't attach the `click` listener to the global `window` object. As your merely interested in clicks happening inside the `<canvas>` element, attach it to this instead.

Second, the `x` and `y` properties returned by the mouseevent don't match what you might expect because it does not take into account the offset of the HTML element on the page. Try using the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties instead.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 700;
const explosion = [];

class Explosion {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.spriteWidth = 200;
    this.spriteHeight = 179;
    this.width = this.spriteWidth / 2;
    this.height = this.spriteHeight / 2;
    this.image = new this.image();
    this.image.src = "boom.png";
    this.frame = 0;
  }

}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 50, 50);

});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" style="background: #eeeeee"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's actually often better to listen to the events on the window rather than on the canvas. For instance here there is a 25px radius around the canvas border that can't be reached (e.g the user can't fill only 2px of the corners, they have to paint at least a 25x25px square. (Edit, that was assuming the fillRect was centered which it isn't in this demo, so they actually have to draw a 50x50 on the top left corner and can draw a smaller one on the bottom right corner)